# Change detection doesn't run when loading auth2 from Google API

Tags: angular, google-api, angular2-observables, angular2-changedetection, google-api-js-client

I'm trying to load the script `https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=initGapi` from within an Angular 2 service in order to make calls to the Google API, but whenever I try to return a value when the script is done loading and initializing, the `async` pipe doesn't want to render the value to the template.

I'm using an `EventEmitter` that fires when the `gapi.load()` and `gapi.client.init` is complete, and the observable is subscribed to it in a component. The async pipe doesn't seem to want to read the value, until I click a button within the same component (and possibly fire change detection). Forcing change detection within the component didn't work when I used `tick()` from `ApplicationRef`.

The service that's loading the Google API is as follows:

**google-api.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { User, Client } from '../../+home/models';

declare var gapi: any;

@Injectable()
export class GoogleApiService {

    CLIENT_ID: string = '....apps.googleusercontent.com';
    DISCOVERY_DOCS: string[] = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/admin/directory_v1/rest"];
    SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly';

    authEmitter: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() {
        window['initGapi'] = (ev) => {
            this.handleClientLoad();
        };
        this.loadScript();
    }

    loadScript() {
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=initGapi';
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }

    handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', this.initClient.bind(this));
    }

    initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
            discoveryDocs: this.DISCOVERY_DOCS,
            clientId: this.CLIENT_ID,
            scope: this.SCOPES
        }).then(() => {
            this.authEmitter.emit(true);
        });
    }

    get gapi(): Observable<any> {
        return this.authEmitter.map(() => 'hello world');
    }
}
```

And the component reading from the service

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { GoogleApiService } from '../../+core/services';

@Component({
    template: `
    What does the service say?
    {{ api$ | async }}
    <button (click)="click()">Button</button>`
})
export class InviteEmployeesContainer implements OnInit {
    api$: Observable<string>;

    constructor(private gApiService: GoogleApiService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.api$ = this.gApiService.gapi;

        this.gApiService.gapi.subscribe((result) => {
            console.log(result);
        });
    }

    click() {
        console.log('clicked');
    }
}
```

The resulting page prints out the string `What does the service say?` and has a button, but doesn't print the text `hello world` until I click the button, which isn't the desired behaviour, it should be visible on the page immediately.

Additionally, when I subscribe and log to the console using `this.gApiService.gapi.subscribe`, it logs `hello world` when I would expect it to.

Does anyone know how I can use the async pipe to get `hello world` to print to the page when the `authEmitter` fires an event.

Comment: Did you try to return it directly as a getter `get api$() { return this.service.gapi }`. You could also try to use the `ChangeDetectorRef` to force a change detection.

Comment: Returning it directly is no good since I don't want the components to use it before it's ready, it needs to do 2 network requests and run `init` before it can be used, hence why I'm using an observable. I'll try forcing change detection, but I don't think that's a practical long-term solution since this is usually something that I would expect observables to handle no problem.

Comment: You know that you can subscripe with `async` pipe to in before its ready and the components will start using it as soon as it emits data. (as i saw you're only emiting new items after it has loaded)

Comment: @cyrix I'm aware, but this isn't my real use case, just a minimum amount of code required to reproduce the problem because my real implementation is more complex than this.

Comment: I had the same issue and came to the same solution as the only answer to this question. I would love to know what the cause was behind this issue.

Comment: There is an open ticket on Angular project page for this issue. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13957

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution to this problem, the question has a few issues.

First of all, `EventEmitter` should only be used to emit, and should never be subscribed to, so instead I swapped it out with a `Subject`. Normally I'd try to use an observable, but in this case I found a subject more appropriate.

Below is a revised plunker using `Subject` instead of `EventEmitter`. I also commented out `gapi.client.init...` and replaced it with a different promise, since it's not actually part of the problem. Note that in the plunker change detection still isn't run until the button is clicked, which is not expected.

https://plnkr.co/edit/YaFP07N6A4CQ3Zz1SbUi?p=preview

The problem I'm encountering is because `gapi.load('client:auth2', this.initClient.bind(this));` runs `initClient` outside of the Angular 2 zone, which excludes it from change detection.

In order to capture the subject within change detection, we have to run the subject's `next` and `complete` call within the Angular 2 zone. This is done by importing `NgZone` and then modifying the lines:

```
    new Promise((res) => res()).then(() => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        this.authSubject.next(true);
        this.authSubject.complete(true);
      });
    });
```

[See the final (resolved) plunker here.](https://plnkr.co/edit/w2UBDiLO7fSoANhLZPEA?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else struggling with this, you also need to wrap any other gapi promise result.

Similar to the above solution this is what I have been using:

```
export function nonZoneAwarePromiseToObservable(promise: Promise<T>, zone: NgZone): Observable<T> {
  return new Observable<T>(subscriber => {
    promise
      .then((v) => {
        zone.run(() => {
          subscriber.next(v)
          subscriber.complete()
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        zone.run(() => {
          subscriber.error(error)
        })
      })
  })
}
```

How I am using it:

```
const calendar: typeof  gapi.client.calendar = _gapi.client.calendar
        const $timezone = calendar.settings.get({setting: 'timezone'})
        return nonZoneAwarePromiseToObservable($timezone, this.zone)
          .pipe(map((timezoneResponse) => timezoneResponse?.result?.value))
```