# Angular 4 UI not updating from observable subscription

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have an observable in a service that I have subscribed to in my app component. Data is being passed through the subscription no issues, but for some reason I cannot get the UI to update with the new information.  I know that the data is getting there because it is being logged to the console.

Here is my app.component code:

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {UserDetailsService} from './services/user-details.service';
import {User} from './shared/models/user';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  title = 'the Portfolio';
  user: User;
  userSub: Subscription;

  constructor(public userDetails: UserDetailsService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userSub = this.userDetails.user$.subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
      console.log(user);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.userSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

User login component where I update the observable:

```
import {Component, AfterViewInit, NgZone} from '@angular/core';
import {UserDetailsService} from '../services/user-details.service';
import {User} from '../shared/models/user';

declare const gapi: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-login',
  templateUrl: './user-login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-login.component.css']
})

export class UserLoginComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private _zone: NgZone, private userDetails: UserDetailsService) {
    console.log(this);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    gapi.load('auth2', () => {
      const auth = gapi.auth2.init({
        'clientId': 'YOURID.apps.googleusercontent.com'
      });

      auth.attachClickHandler('google-login-button', {},
        (googleUser) => {
          const profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
          // console.log('Token || ' + googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
          // console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
          // console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
          // console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
          // console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());

          this.userDetails.setLoginUser(new User({
            id: profile.getId(),
            name: profile.getName(),
            email: profile.getEmail()
          }));
        },
        (error) => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
        });
    });
  }
}
```

User details service:

```
import {Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {User} from '../shared/models/user';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class UserDetailsService implements OnInit {

  private userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(new User());
  user$ = this.userSubject.asObservable();

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  public setLoginUser(user: User) {
    this.userSubject.next(user);
  }
}
```

And here is my UI code:

```
<div *ngIf="user" class="alert alert-success">{{user.name}}</div>
{{user.name}}
```

What am I missing? Been stuck on this for over a day now.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Any messages in the console, along with the log?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure as I'm just starting with angular 2/4 but aren't you missing the `async` pipe? `*ngIf="user | async"`

Comment: @jonrsharpe no errors in the console, just the standard XHR finished messages

Comment: @maurycy that would only be if they exposed the observable to the component directly. `user: User;` here, not `user: Observable<User>;`

Comment: @maurycy as far as I know the async keyword is required if i'm not manually subscribing in the code. but I have tried 
    {{(userDetails.user$).name | async}} and it still doesn't update the ui

Comment: @MattBH well that should be `{{(userDetails.user$ | async).name}}`, and I'd *definitely* expect Angular to shout at you over that. Are you running in some production mode with errors/warnings suppressed? That would explain why it's failing quietly. You'll need to provide more information for a [mcve] here - could you provide more information and a Plunker to reproduce?

Comment: Working in dev mode, tried that but still nothing, gimme a sec and I'll try setup a Plunker.

Comment: I found the answer, thanks for your help guys

Comment: In that case this appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/42660643/3001761 - that library operates *outside* Angular change detection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. When I was updating the service using the setLoginUser function I did this:

```
this.userDetails.setLoginUser(new User({
              id: profile.getId(),
              name: profile.getName(),
              email: profile.getEmail()
            }));
```

I needed to do this:

```
this._zone.run(() =>{
            this.userDetails.setLoginUser(new User({
              id: profile.getId(),
              name: profile.getName(),
              email: profile.getEmail()
            }));
          });
```

Now both ways are working:

```
<div *ngIf="user" class="alert alert-success">{{user.name}}</div>
{{(userDetails.user$ | async).name}}
```

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Note that this code doesn't even appear in your question, and there's no explanation of *why* this caused this problem and *how* the change fixes it; that makes it unlikely to be useful to anyone else. I'm glad you've solved the problem, but you should probably just delete the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I didn't think it was the issue as the data was getting to the app component. It just wasn't updating the UI.

Comment: `this.userDetails.setLoginUser` **still** only appears in the answer. It's not at all clear why you'd need to wrap that in an explicit zone.run.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'll update the original question.

Comment: if you need to use ngZone to trigger change detection on an observable, you're doing something very very wrong.

Comment: @bryan60 I think that it's something to do with the Google Auth library and the scope that it runs in. You'll notice that when I initialize gapi that I use quite a few nested () => functions. I had to do that because when I tried to use component functions e.g. this.success, I was getting "this is not defined".

Comment: Do you really think angular (made by google) can't work with google auth without a hack? You're not integrating the external library correctly. You're accessing it like a global variable on the window that you've declared, this is almost universally a bad practice.

Comment: @bryan60 Very constructive comment, you're not giving any explanation or solution. And you're actually wrong because gapi.js is by default exposed on the window scope when importing the library and is the way it's used in every documentation from Google. Importing the library as an external one is not a bad practise either and is supported by ng-cli (by Google). Lastly, manually triggering the change detection with ngZone is the right solution in that case.

Comment: If you want an explanation concerning why Zone doesn't detect the change by default you can check [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/do-you-still-think-that-ngzone-zone-js-is-required-for-change-detection-in-angular-16f7a575afef).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need that zone run because in similar case in my application I didn't need. I use getter and setter method in service. Can you check this out here https://github.com/JanneHarju/MultiSourcePlayList/blob/master/angular2App/app/services/playlist.service.ts
getPlaylistsModified() function.

Comment: Thanks @Janne but I think that it has something to do with the Google auth library that I'm using. As I said the service was getting the data, just that the UI wasn't updating.